# create new dataframe out of selected row from multi dataframe pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have three dataframes. I want to select the row by date `2020-10-26` from all 3 dataframes and than I want to create a new dataframe. How to do it?

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date

date1 = date.fromisoformat('2020-10-25')
date2 = date.fromisoformat('2020-10-26')
date3 = date.fromisoformat('2020-10-27')

for x in range(3):
    df = pd.DataFrame([(date1,f'Stu{x}j', x+1, f'Varan{x}j', x*400+2), 
                        (date2,f'aja{x}k', x+2, f'Del{x}j', x*634+3), 
                        (date3,f'Aadi{x}t', x+4, f'Mumb{x}j', x*454+4),
                        (date2,f'har{x}h', x+5, f'bom{x}j', x*124+5)],
                       columns =['Date','Name', 'Age',  
                             'City', 'Salary'])
    df.set_index('Date', inplace = True)
    print(df)
```

Comment: What is your expected output? How to deal with conflicting contents at the same date and the same column name(s)?

Answer (score 1):

Below code would help you

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date

date1 = date.fromisoformat('2020-10-25')
date2 = date.fromisoformat('2020-10-26')
date3 = date.fromisoformat('2020-10-27')
res = pd.DataFrame()
for x in range(3):
    df = pd.DataFrame([(date1,f'Stu{x}j', x+1, f'Varan{x}j', x*400+2), 
                        (date2,f'aja{x}k', x+2, f'Del{x}j', x*634+3), 
                        (date3,f'Aadi{x}t', x+4, f'Mumb{x}j', x*454+4),
                        (date2,f'har{x}h', x+5, f'bom{x}j', x*124+5)],
                       columns =['Date','Name', 'Age',  
                             'City', 'Salary'])
    temp = df[df['Date'].isin([date2])]
    res = res.append(temp)
print(res)
```

Old method:

```
fr = [df1, df2, df3]
full = pd.concat(fr).reset_index()
full[full.Date.isin([date2])]
```

Comment: error `ObjectHashTable.get_item KeyError: 'Date'` @SubbuVidyaSekar

Comment: yes but my real code is different then this dummy code I think your previous solution was correct please write the last two step after combining all df @SubbuVidyaSekar

Comment: Added the old method in the answer @stackdotpop

Comment: still not working if we select row  and append it in empty df in every iteration I think it will work what do you think??@SubbuVidyaSekar

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223760/discussion-between-subbu-vidyasekar-and-stackdotpop).

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
row1 = df1.loc[date2, :]
row2 = df2.loc[date2, :]
row3 = df3.loc[date2, :]
pd.concat([row1,row2,row3], axis=1).T
```

Output:

```
            Name    Age City        Salary
2020-10-26  ajay    32  Delhi       25000
2020-10-26  Saumya  32  Kanpur      20000
2020-10-26  Aaditya 40  Dehradun    24000
```

Comment: How to achive this on a loop I have changed my code please visit again Thankyou @Marcus